# Triangle Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have code like this

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let output = "";
  for (let j = i; j <= 5; j++) {
    output += j
  }
  console.log(output);
}
```

the output I want is very different,
want like this

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

but instead they came out:

```
12345
2345
345
45
5
```

anyone want to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will work. It is needed to update the `j` loop by reverse to get the result.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let output = "";
  for (let j = 5; j >= i; j --) {
    output += 5 - j + 1;
  }
  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: Can you pls approve my answer if this helps?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
    let output = "";
    for (let j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
        output = j + output;
    }
    console.log(output);
}
```

Logs :

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Comment: There’s an easier way to do it though. You can do it by setting string to be 12345 and then removing first character on each line until it’s length is 1.